# Can I use a reinterpret_cast here?

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion, reinterpret-cast

Simplified, I have the following class template:

```
template<class T> class Buffer{
  char * ptr;
  T * getPtr(){return (T*)ptr;} // (1) Which cast to use ?
}
```

A number of these Buffer is generated from a file and stored into an array when I do not know their type T yet.

```
Buffer<char> buffers[10];
do_something_to_load_buffers_from_file();
```

Finally, when I know their type, I want to return them by value by a function:

```
template<class T> Buffer<T> getBuffer(int i){
  return (Buffer<T>)buffers[i]; // (2) Which cast to use ?
}
...
Buffer<int> ibuf = getBuffer<int>(5);
```

The question is now: Which casts do I use on the marked lines? (I INTENTIONALLY used C-style cast in the given example as a PLACEHOLDER.)

Mark (1):
A reinterpret cast should do the right thing here, is that true?

Mark (2):

- A reinterpret cast would also do the job here, but is it good practice?
- For my general understanding: This line will first call the conversion constructor Buffer(Buffer& b) and after return, the move constructor is called. Right?

Comment: C style casts are never a good idea.

Comment: @n.m.: OP states it is a placeholder for one of the C++ cast.

Comment: Why `char * ptr;` in first place, instead of `T * ptr;`?

Comment: For Mark2, why not create a specific constructor ?

Comment: Why char * ptr? Right, I could also use T * ptr. But nevertheless, I would have to cast, since first I load the buffer as plain characters from a file, not knowing its actual type. Later on, I will use the getBuffer(...) to get the buffer with the right type.

Comment: Jarod42: That's my question... Should I use a specific constructor here, should I use reinterpret cast, or should I do something else ;-)

Comment: @Michael the cast should be at load-time, not fetch time. And "... to get the buffer with the right type" sounds like you're essentially trying to roll your own *variant* type. Is that correct?

Comment: @WhozCraig: I simply DO NOT KNOW the type at load time, that's the problem...

Comment: @Michael It's pretty questionable that a number of `char`'s read from a file would replicate a valid instance of `T` properly. You'll need serialization mechanisms to achieve such. The answer is: No `reinterpret_cast<T*>` or any other cast operation is blatantly wrong for this case.

Comment: @Michael so.. was that a yes, you're rolling a variant? And remembering the type specified as `T` in `Buffer<T>` is a *compile-time* determination, are you then, based on some runtime-detection, falling through decision tree that somehow chooses the *right* `T` (and the caller knows this.. how)? It was a simple question to what is *not* a simple problem, and whether you considered that was the only reason I (now regretfully) asked. I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Yes, that's exactly what I need to do. From my point of view, this is a relatively easy task, but I would be more than happy if you could show me the difficulties I obviously don't see.

Answer (score 3):

You may use the following:

```
template<class T> class Buffer{
  char * ptr;
  T * getPtr(){return reinterpret_cast<T*>(ptr);}

  template<typename U>
  Buffer(const Buffer<U>& rhs) : ptr(rhs.ptr) {}
};
```

And so later:

```
template<class T> Buffer<T> getBuffer(int i){
  return buffers[i];
}
```

Comment: +1 belaying the overall idea and its merit in the first place, this can/will turn anything into anything else and the cross-typing via template-constructor is elegant. Ownership of the original pointer is obviously an issue, but none-the-less its still an interesting approach.

Answer (score 3):

1. `reinterpret_cast` is the obvious choice here, because that's what we are doing: reinterpreting the bit pattern stored in a `char*` as if it was a `T*`.
2. No built-in cast is a good idea here. `Buffer<char>` and `Buffer<T>` are unrelated. Nothing is guaranteed about their layout compatibility (or at least you need to define them very carefully to ensure layout compatibility). On platforms where `char*` is longer than other pointers, this is likely to break hard.

One possible way of dealing with it is this:

```
class Buffer{
  char * ptr;
  template <typename T>
  T * getPtr() {return reinterpret_cast<T*>(ptr);}
};
```

Another way is cross-type copying `Buffer<T>` as the other answer suggests.